# jquery+grails, how to pass input data from a dialog into controller

Tags: java, javascript, html, grails, groovy

I'm new to grails and jquery.

I have created a jquery dialog like this example : http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

open a dialog, enter data, and display the data in the table on the main page.

the table is dynamic, after adding all the entries into the table
I want to create a save button, which will save all the data into db, 
My question is how to pass all the data in the table into the controller so that the controller can persist the data?

here's my gsp:

```
        <fieldset class="form">
            <h2>ReportInstance</h2>
            <table id="reportInstances" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Template</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button id="create_new_reportInstance">Create new Report
                Instance</button>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="buttons">
            <g:submitToRemote controller="NewReport" action="saveReport"
                update="page-body" value="save" />
        </fieldset>
    </g:form>


 javascript:

           $("#dialog-form").dialog(
               {
                autoOpen : false,
                    height : 300,
                    width : 350,
                    modal : true,
                buttons : {
                 "Create an account" : function() {
                          var bValid = true;
                           allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
                                if (bValid) {
                                    $("#reportInstances    tbody").append(
                                    "<tr>" + "/<td>" + name.val() + "/</td>"
                                            + "/<td>" + template.val()
                                            + "/</td>" + "/<td>" + "/</tr>");

                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    Cancel : function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close : function() {
                    allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
                }
            });

    $("#create_new_reportInstance").button().click(function() {
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    });
```

I just want to pass name.val() and template.val() into controller

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the `submitToRemote` at all.  Since you are already using jQuery you could post this via Ajax:

```
if(bValid) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/yourApp/newReport/saveReport",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"name": name.val(), "template": template.val()},
        success: function(data) {
            $("#reportInstances tbody").append( "" + "/" + name.val() + "/" + "/" + template.val() + "/" + "/" + "/");
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
           //whatever you need to do here - output errors etc.
           console.log(xhr.statusText);
           console.log(textStatus);
           console.log(error);
        }

    });
}
```

In your controller you will get a `params.name` and a `params.template`

Also note the lower case first letter on the controller name - in Grails the `NewReportController` is accessed as `newReport`

Comment: thanks, do you know how can I submit multiple entries of the table contents together? maybe like in a list

Comment: Hi Kelly, thanks for your answer, I use submitToRemote because there are other textfield in the same g:form, I try to create a page and send all the client input together, the jquery dialog is one of the components on the page, do you know how to put g:textfield and this dialog together in one form, and send the data together to controller?

Comment: For your first comment - do you need to submit more than one new entry from the dialog?  What is the purpose of sending more than just the entry you are adding?

Comment: So you have one main form, then the dialog is like a sub-form that just handles the "New Report" - is that correct?  In that case you could do as I showed for the dialog sub-form: each time you submit the dialog it creates a "New Report."  Then just have your normal form elements in the `g:form` tags and use a normal submit rather than a `submitToRemote`  If this is not what you are trying to do I don't understand the point of having the dialog form and then a standard form...

Comment: @Kelly please can you take a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269570/creating-a-grail-jquery-modal-window-and-form-posting-with-ajax