# Creating a Grail Jquery Modal Window and Form posting with ajax?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, grails, grails-plugin, grails-controller

I have the following code :

```
<body>
        <div id="dialog-form" title="Create a new Comment">
        <form>
        <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Enter your Comment Please </label>
        <textarea rows="6" cols="2" name="commentArea" id="commentArea" ></textarea>
        </fieldset>
         </form>
        </div>
        <button id="create-user">Create new user</button>
</body>
```

and my Modal Window using jquery-UI

```
     <g:javascript>
      $(function(){
    $("#dialog-form").dialog ({
    autoOpen:false,
    height:300,
    resizable:false,
    width:350,
    modal:true,
    buttons: {
    "Attach Comment": function() {
    alert('assum it already submitted'); // ? ? ? this time what can i add to post a form to  a controller attachComments with commentArea posted.

    $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    Cancel: function() {
    $(this).dialog("close");
    }
    },
    close: function() {
    alert(Form is cloased!); 
    $(this).dialog("close");
    }
    });

   $( "#create-user" )
  .button()
  .click(function() {
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
  });

         }); 
</g:javascript>
```

The above code draws my modal window but how can i post the form to attachCommentController and receive responses back to to show errors on modal window?

Comment: You'll need to use ajax to make a request to the server without refreshing the browser.  Then, based on the response you get back, either close the modal or show errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Using implementation case 1 is to use ajax and display error or success on the opened dialog :

So , i have added the following ajax code on above code section ...

```
"Attach Comment": function() {
        //do form posting here
        $.ajax({ 
        context: $(this),
        url:"${resource()}"+"/issue/attachComment",
        type:"POST",
        data:{"comment":$('#commentArea').val(),"id":$("#selectedIssueInstanceId").val()},
        success:function(data){
        if(data.success)
        {
        var tobeAppendeID = $("#selectedIssueInstanceId").val();
        $('#'+'comment_'+tobeAppendeID).val(data.newComment);
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
        else
        {
        $('#error-message').addClass('ui-state-error ui-corner-all');
        $("#error-message").html(data.message).show()
        $(this).dialog("close");
        }
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can Use remote form or remote links, or ajax calls to interact with the controllers and you will be able to get the response back to your view, you can receive it in some other div.

for example it can be done through remoteForm like below:

On your view you can use remote form like:

```
    <g:formRemote  
         name="productForm"
        url="[controller: 'attachCommentController', action:'save']"
        update="resultsDiv"
                >
       <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Enter your Comment Please </label>
        <textarea rows="6" cols="2" name="commentArea" id="commentArea" ></textarea>
    <inuput type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Value"/>
        </fieldset>
    </g:formRemote>
   <div id="resultsDiv">You will receive your response here</div>
```

This way you will be able to get the response back to your modal window.

Comment: cool@ how to pass the controll from the modal window  "Attach Comment": function to the execution of the <g:remote> ?

Comment: I didn't get the question properly can you please brief it a bit.

Comment: Ok , let say i pressed attach comment button --> then how do i intergrate your form and the dialog click event to post your forms :)

Comment: :) still not sure about the prob, may be I am thinking something else, what I got is, you want to link the submitted value back to parent page rather than modal, if it is I think you can place response div on that page itself, for multiple comments response div id can be generated dynamically.
One more thing if you want response on multiple places like on the comments section along with the modal, then you can append a trigger on success of the form remote and place the same content on that div.
:)
not sure if this is what you want.