# How to open a modal-form, execute a action in the controller, and render the result in Grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails, modal-dialog

I have a table in my gsp where each row have a button to edit. This button open a modal panel with the form to edit this row.
When I open this modal, a js function run and make an ajax call to an action of the controller, passing the id of the row. 
In the controller I search for the entity and then I return it to the view. But the problem is that in the view I can't see this object..

The code I have is:

*GSP*:

```
<a href="#modal-form" data-id="${cancha?.id}" role="button" class="open-EditCanchaModal btn btn-xs btn-info" data-toggle="modal" />
```

Then, this modal have a g:formRemote with 4 textFields inside to edit the properties

*JS*:

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-EditCanchaModal", function () {
    var canchaId = $(this).data('id');
    var newData = $.post("${createLink(controller: 'cancha', action: 'selectToEdit')}/"+canchaId);
    alert("dat: "+newData); // it print dat: [object Object]
    alert("can: "+newData.cancha); // it print undefined
});
```

*GRAILS*:

```
def selectToEdit = {
    Cancha cancha = Cancha.get(params.id)
    println cancha // this found the correct "Cancha"
    [cancha:cancha]
}
```

So, I want to get the Cancha in the JS, after call the method selectToEdit, to render the atributes in the textFields of the modal panel.

Comment: I may be missing something here but why don't you just use a form or a remoteForm if you're using ajax?

Comment: Yes, sorry, this modal-form is inside of a <g:formRemote>..
The edit button, open this modal that have a formRemote, y a button in the modal submit to the url indicated on this formRemote.

Comment: Wee I don't know what possibilities you have got but from your remote action can't you point out the id of the <div> or whatever you're using to update the contents?

Comment: Did you mean to use a g:remoteLink to update the div? 
I try this (I comment how to MikeZoo, under this post), with the same results. 
I can execute the action in the controller, but I don't have the return value in the gsp.

Comment: It sounds like you need to update the div using a template that takes you cancha-entity as a model. So when your remote action is called it updates the div by inserting a template with your return entity, I have done this multiple times and it has been able to do the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to Grails.
Correct me if I'm wrong.

Returned newData will be the string format of your object.
( not a real object, think it as the output of toString() )

So, to achieve what you are trying to do.
You may use JSON encode/decode to be the bridge between JS/GRAILS.

Comment: I try changing the return value of the controller to:
[cancha:cancha] as JSON.
But no changes..

Comment: full link for the ajax should be    cancha/selectToEdit/(canchaId), can you post the return value of this ?

Comment: The controller method returns something like this:
{"cancha":{"class":"com.cancha.Cancha","id":1,"cantidadJugadores":5, "nombre":"cancha number 1"}}

And putting this url in the browser execute the method but tell me that (../WEB-INF/grails-app/views/cancha/selectToEdit.jsp) is not available.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, did u solve this already? I think the error msg explains itself. Can you post the link that produced by the createLink ?

Comment: Now I'm trying with this in the gsp: <g:remoteLink controller="cancha" action="selectToEdit" id="${cancha?.id}" update="[success:'modal-form',failure:'error']" after="setCanchaToEdit();" />.
Then function setCanchaToEdit() { $('#modal-form').modal('show'); }.
And the action in the controlled is the same. 
With the first way ($.post("${createLink..)) and with this new way, the url for the POST is http://localhost:8080/myproject/cancha/selectToEdit/5, and the error is 404 (Not Found).

Comment: I try to print ${cancha} (the return value of the action) in the gsp, but is null (I print inside the modal panel, when it shows after click in one of the buttons).

Answer (score 0):

[Creating a Grail Jquery Modal Window and Form posting with ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269570/creating-a-grail-jquery-modal-window-and-form-posting-with-ajax)

some excerpt :

```
"Attach Comment": function() {
        //do form posting here
        $.ajax({ 
        context: $(this),
        url:"${resource()}"+"/issue/attachComment",
        type:"POST",
        data:{"comment":$('#commentArea').val(),"id":$("#selectedIssueInstanceId").val()},
        success:function(data){
        if(data.success)
        {
        var tobeAppendeID = $("#selectedIssueInstanceId").val();
        $('#'+'comment_'+tobeAppendeID).val(data.newComment);
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
        else
        {
        $('#error-message').addClass('ui-state-error ui-corner-all');
        $("#error-message").html(data.message).show()
        $(this).dialog("close");
        }
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
```

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I try with:

`$.ajax({ 
    context: $(this),
    url:"selectToEdit/"+canchaId,
    type:"POST",
    data:{"id":canchaId},
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});`

And with this `url:"selectToEdit",`

With the same results: ../cancha/selectToEdit/1 `404 (Not Found)`

Comment: noticed this /issue/attachComment is the controller which the code is refering
def comment () {
def id = params?.id?.toLong()
println "Recieved ID is ${id}" 

}

Comment: Yes, I'm reciving right the id in the action controller. 
But then I haven't the return value of the action in the gsp.

Comment: hey ! return value ?? you can use your browser 'inspect' to see that but it is actaully 'data'